# price of Token distrubition

Tags: go-ethereum, ico, tokens, price

can someone tell me how the transaction work is it in USD OR Price of ETH / BTC ?

lets say

1 ETH = 900 $ TOKEN GIVEN 3000

when the price increased to 1000 $ then the token given to investor will be based on ethereum or usd ?

Comment: If eth value is increased that not means that all token prices are increased.

Comment: not about price , about total number of token given to the investors ! will the number of token increased if the price increase or it dont have anything to do with the price ? during sale ?

Answer (score 0):

The tokens price is defined **only by market**. So, if you sold 3000 tokens for 900$ (users have spent 900$), and then the price of Ethers is increased, then, in the next moment, the price of your tokens (most probably, because it is market - there nothing is quaranteed) **will stay the same in UDS** - $900. Hence - in ethers - it will decrease. Because tokens price is related to real world (actual usd money), but not to some intermediate "almost-currency" like Ethers.

Comment: I don't see any reason why you can't have a crowdsale which sells for example 1 token for 1 ETH.